# Subsetting using two conditions

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have a data frame with two columns

```
df <- data.frame(vec1 = c("a","b","c","d"), vec2 = c("2022","2011","2020","1246"))
```

df

```
 vec1 vec2
   a  2022
   b  2011
   c  2020
   d  1246
```

I want to use vec1 & vec2 together to subset another data frame for extracting values. The data frame i want to subset from looks like

```
df1 <- data.frame(name=c(rep('a',4),rep('b',1),rep('c',5),rep('d',3),rep('e',2)), title=c(rep("2022",2),rep("201",2),rep("2011",1),rep("2020",5),rep("1246",1),rep("1256",2),rep("0000",2)))
```

df1

```
  name title
1     a  2022
2     a  2022
3     a   201
4     a   201
5     b  2011
6     c  2020
7     c  2020
8     c  2020
9     c  2020
10    c  2020
11    d  1246
12    d  1256
13    d  1256
14    e  0000
15    e  0000
```

for example

```
subset(df1,df1$name%in%df$vec1 && df1$title%in%df$vec2)
```

- what i am trying to do is "a" & "2022" from df should match "a" and "2022" in df1 and should not match "a" and "201". Same should be the case for all other entries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A simple merge would work well because it will match all the columns specified in the `by=` arguments

```
merge(df, df1, by.x=names(df), by.y=names(df1))
#   vec1 vec2
# 1    a 2022
# 2    a 2022
# 3    b 2011
# 4    c 2020
# 5    c 2020
# 6    c 2020
# 7    c 2020
# 8    c 2020
# 9    d 1246
```

Answer (score 2):

Or a `data.table` method would be

```
library(data.table)
setkeyv(setDT(df1),names(df1))[df]
#    name title
#1:    a  2022
#2:    a  2022
#3:    b  2011
#4:    c  2020
#5:    c  2020
#6:    c  2020
#7:    c  2020
#8:    c  2020
#9:    d  1246
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `semi_join()` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
semi_join(df1, df, by = c("title" = "vec2", "name" = "vec1"))
```

Or `filter()`:

```
df1 %>% filter(title %in% with(df, vec2), name %in% with(df, vec1))
```

Answer (score 0):

`&` is vectorized (meaning it can return a vector) while `&&` cannot. Since you want to return indices, you must use `&`. You also do not need to specify the underlying data in a `subset` function call.

```
df <- data.frame(vec1 = c("a","b","c","d"), vec2 = c("2022","2011","2020","1246"))


df1 <- data.frame(name=c(rep('a',4),rep('b',1),rep('c',5),rep('d',3),rep('e',2)), title=c(rep("2022",2),rep("201",2),rep("2011",1),rep("2020",5),rep("1246",1),rep("1256",2),rep("0000",2)))


> subset(df1, name %in% df$vec1 & title %in% df$vec2)
   name title
1     a  2022
2     a  2022
5     b  2011
6     c  2020
7     c  2020
8     c  2020
9     c  2020
10    c  2020
11    d  1246
```

Comment: @StevenBeaupré because he wants to subset based on two criteria.